# Why doesn't the Back and Forth Method for Infinite Random Grap use the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: graph-theory

[A way to proof](http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/rado-graph-and-0-1-law-for-finite-graphs/) that any two Rado graphs (countably infinite nodes, has graph extension property) are isomorphic, is to use the back and forth method.

At each step of the method, we have a vertex $v$ in one graph. Using the graph extension property, we find (possibly countable infinite) vertices to map $v$ to.

Since we have to choose one of those vertices, why doesn't this use the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick look at the proof you link, at the beginning, we fixed an enumeration of each graph.  Then at each step, we choose the lowest-numbered vertex that does what we want.  We are making a specific choice, not an arbitrary one, so the axiom of choice is not needed.

Comment: You choose the lowest numbered vertex, then that link says by property "P", there exists a vertex $z$ satisfying certain property. We still have to pick one from all those vertices. But you are right, there is a "canonical" choice: pick the one with the lowest number. Thanks! + 1 and accepted.